# What is the difference between $Γ⊭Φ$ and $Γ⊭¬Φ$?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

Did I understand this correctly?

1. $Γ⊨Φ$ ($Φ$ is considered true)
2. $Γ⊨¬Φ$ ($Φ$ is considered false)
3. $Γ⊭Φ$ ($Φ$ is considered neither true nor false)
4. $Γ⊭¬Φ$ ???

Please help me understand. How can we know (Γ⊭Φ) → (Γ⊨¬Φ) ? Is Church's theorem on the form Γ⊢¬Φ (Proving that there is no algorithm..)

Comment: As for the last part, we can't. Take $\Gamma$ to be a single sentence $\gamma$. And take $\delta$ to be a completely "disjoint" sentence (i.e. there is no variable appearing in both sentences), then $\Gamma\not\models\delta$ but also $\Gamma\not\models\lnot\delta$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Of course. What happens if δ is the empty sentence {} ?

Comment: There is no empty sentence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The notation $\models$, as opposed to $\vdash$, is about truth, not about provability.

$\Gamma\models\Phi$ means $\Phi$ is true in every structure in which every member of $\Gamma$ is true.

$\Gamma\not\models\Phi$ means it is not the case that $\Phi$ is true in every structure in which every member of $\Gamma$ is true.  That means there is at least one structure in which every member of $\Gamma$ is true and $\Phi$ is not true.

$\Gamma\models¬\Phi$ means $¬\Phi$ is true in every structure in which every member of $\Gamma$ is true.  The difference between this and the statement preceding it is the difference between "at least one" and "every".

Comment: _"That means there is at least one structure in which every member of $\Gamma$ is true and $\Phi$ is not true."_ -- Is it possible that there are no structures in which every member of $\Gamma$ is true? (it would imply that there are no structures in which every member of $\Gamma$ is true __and__ $\Phi$ is not true)